# Convert string with HASH MD5 to ToBase64String

Tags: c#, hash, type-conversion, base64, md5

this is my problem,

i have this code that accepts clean text with passwords and returns Base64MD5 hashes

```
    private static string GetMd5Base64Pass(string userpwd)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userpwd)));
    }
```

And i need to reuse it to accept MD5 string hashes and return in Base64MD5.

i tried to do this:

```
    private static string GetMd5Base64PassMD5(string userpwd)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userpwd));
    }
```

but the returns are completely different.

already tried to convert the string to bytearray, didn't work.

I need to insert one string with 32bits MD5, and return it in Base64String.

thks

------------------------------ Edited

Example:

Password is 123123:

MD5 is: 4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93

Base64String of MD5 is: Qpf0SxOVUjUkWySXOZ16kw==

I need to get

this: Qpf0SxOVUjUkWySXOZ16kw==

from

this hash string
4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93

Comment: I don't understand...of course a string and its hash are completely different. "I need to insert one string with 32bits MD5, and return it in Base64String." but actually GetMd5Base64PassMD5 does that. What's wrong? What do you mean with "insert"? Merge them?

Comment: its supposed to do that, but the string that each of them return are different

Comment: i added one little edit with examples

Comment: You get what you need - where is your problem?

Comment: Some problems with your code: 1) You silently corrupt passwords containing non-ASCII characters. Use `Encoding.Utf8` instead of `Encoding.ASCII`. 2) MD5 is not a good password hash. A password hash needs to be slow and salted. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) 3) Your send code doesn't hash at all. It directly encodes the password with Base64, which is essentially the same as storing the plaintext 4) What do you mean by 32 bit MD5. MD5 returns 128 bits, 16 bytes, 32 hex characters or 44 Base64 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static string ConvertHexStringToBase64(string hexString)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i++)
        {
            buffer[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16));
            i += 1;
        }
        string res = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        return res;
    }
```

this receives md5 string hashes and transforms it to Base64 Hex