# Convert string with HEX MD5 to base64 encoding

Tags: python, hash, encoding, base64, md5

I need to convert a HEX-type md5 string to the base64 version in Python.

For example, if I had MD5: `4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93`

I need the code to produce `Qpf0SxOVUjUkWySXOZ16kw==`

This is identical to another SO asking for a [C# implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20374524), but I need the Python code. This is similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5305456) asking to convert a single binary number to base64 in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the version of Python you are running, the following will work:

## Python 2

```
base64.b64encode("4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93".decode("‌​hex"))
```

## Python 3

```
base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex("4297f44b13955235245b2497399d‌​7a93"))
```